# Можно ли в windows воспроизводить звук при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры?

Tags: python, windows

Нашёл [приложение](http://www.soundplant.org/), которое позволяет это делать, и мне стало интересно можно ли это сделать какими-либо встроенными программами(не имею ввиду кнопки-переключатели Caps Lock,Num Lock их звук можно включить в панели управления)? Это можно сделать на питоне кодом, приведённым ниже, но у меня `winsound.PlaySound` не хочет находить файл и просто воспроизводит системный звук ошибки. Данный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830045/playing-sound-from-a-specific-location-in-python-tkinter) не помог(ни через sys, ни через создание папки).
Код:

```
import winsound
import keyboard
duration = 250
q = 300
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\some.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)            
            winsound.Beep(q, duration)#Тк PlaySound не хочет, приходится через писк
    except:
        break
```

Comment: У меня есть пример, но там через `pyqt5` сделано: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7695cdb024058aed290e4dc39077fa2794eb935d/play_sound__pyqt5/main.py#L38

Comment: @gil9red, А не подскажите как и что из чего запускать? А то после запуска main. После `process.start()` не воспроизводится и заканчивается выполнение. :)

Comment: Что-то вроде такого: `play_async('C:\\some.wav')`. Если не нужно асинхронно запускать, то просто через `play('C:\\some.wav')`. Асинхронный работает через создание процессов